# Array Loops, making an application to add team names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am completely new to JavaScript having spent years lost in my CSS bubble. I am now at college and I have been asked to prepare an application that would allow 7 clubs to enter their teams name into the system, show each one on the screen and then have the full list viewable numbered 1-7.

I so far have this code:

```
document.write("<h3> Names 1-7</h3>");
// adds header to top of page

var football= new Array(7)

for (var count=0; count<7; count++) {
    football [count] = windows.prompt ("Enter team name","");
    }
    {
        document.write(football[count] + "<br />");
    }
```

I'm close to pulling hair out, nothing is working.
Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo there, use `window` not `windows`.

So use,

```
football [count] = window.prompt ("Enter team name","");
```

also move `document.write` inside the loop..

```
document.write("<h3> Names 1-7</h3>");
// adds header to top of page

var football= new Array(7)

for (var count=0; count<7; count++) {
    football [count] = window.prompt ("Enter team name","");
     document.write(football[count] + "<br />");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with javascript for a long time, but I believe your for loop is incorrect, thus not working properly. It should be:

```
for (var count=0; count<7; count++) {
    football [count] = window.prompt ("Enter team name","");
    document.write(football[count] + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window` not `windows`,

ex.

```
var football= new Array(7);

for (var count=0; count<football.length; count++) 
    football [count] = window.prompt ("Enter team name " + (count+1) + " : ","");

document.write("<h3> Names 1-7</h3>");

for (var count=0; count<football.length; count++) 
    document.write ( football [count] + "<br>");
```